# how to append a list in href url?

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest

I want to append a list in the url that is a href ,how can do so and how can i read it using `request.getParameter()` ? or a complete bean object in the url ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the same name for every item, build something like this, `http://example.com/somepath?amt=1&amt=2&amt=3`.

And then you can use `HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap()`. Or alternatively, you can use `HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues(name)`. You might like to use the latter by specifying the name, for example,

```
String[] amts = request.getParameterValues("amt");
```

By the way, `getParameterMap()` will give you a Map object having parameter names as key. It will have all other request parameters as well as your 'amt'.

```
Map map = request.getParameterMap();
String[] amts = map.get("amt");
```

Comment: i am appending the list has
"&amt="+c.getamt().getList())
HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap() would give the complete list without specifyng the name amt ?

Comment: HttpServletRequest.getParameterMap() is failing ,i am appending the list in a url .please update the answer

Comment: getParameterMap will give you a Map object having parameter names as key. It will have all other request parameters as well as your 'amt'. So, you might like to go with the latter one.

Comment: Moreover, you need to create your URL something like this, `http://example.com/somepath?amt=1&amt=2&amt=3`

Comment: HashMap map=(HashMap) getRequest().getParameterMap();
log.info("key is ::"+map.get("amt").toString());
is it some thing like this ?how wil it give me the value ?

Comment: Try this, and please take my advice and make a habit to read the docs. See my addendum.

Comment: It returns a `String[]`. By the way, `getParameterValues()` way is preferred.

Comment: getParameterValues() is returning me a string[] ,i am appending a complete list in the usrl as amt=somelist ,how would i get the complete list using getParameterValues("amt") ?please clarify it.

Comment: you must do this: http://example.com/somepath?amt=1&amt=2&amt=3; note that the same parameter is appended several times.

Comment: How can i append amt=1&amt=2&amt=3 when my list size will be changing always.

Comment: i just want to read the valueof amt whose value is a list whose size varies always i cant add amt=1&amt=2...

Comment: Don't tell me, you can't loop over your list? Its that simple. You even do it in your JSP using JSTL/EL. And doing it in Java is no problem at all.